# How to get more than 1000 distance matrix with "osrm" package

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate more distances In R using the package "osrm". I don't know what I am doing wrong because I followed all the steps of the package. When I try to use the argument `max-table-size`, it returns an error.

I already tried to put the argument `max-table-size` into the code, but that doesn't work.

I tried to do this:

```
distancias <- osrmTable(loc = dist[1:100, c("id","lon","lat")]"max-table-size")
```

when I try this, I have this error:

> The OSRM server returned an error: Error in names(src) <- c("id",
>   "lon", "lat"): 'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the
>   vector [1]

```
library(osrm)

dist <- read.table ("C:\\Users\\hammer\\Documents\\Erick\\22-05-19\\Distancias\\mg.txt", header=TRUE, sep="\t")


distancias <- osrmTable(loc = dist[1:100, c("id","lon","lat")])


write.table(distancias, file = "dist.txt", sep="\t")
```

I hope get one distance matrix of 3.600 x 3.600

Comment: Since we don’t know what your data look like, it’s hard to say exactly what is causing the error. I think though that “loc” doesn’t have same number of rows as “lat”, “long”, and “id”. All of those should have same number of rows. Next time add `dput( head( yourdata))` to your question so we know what the data look like.

Comment: Thank you a lot to answer. My data has 3 rows, one with the id (city code) et two other rows with the coordinates. When I try with less then 100 cases, work very well, the problem it's when I try to get more than that.

Answer (score 6):

The `osrm` statement on the maximum number of locations supported is:

> If you want to get a large number of distances make sure to set the "max-table-size" argument (Max. locations supported in table) of the OSRM server accordingly.

This statement concerns the OSRM server, not the R package `osrm`. 
If you use your own server you can change the number of locations supported in an `osrmTable()` call.

This example using the [docker image provided by OSRM](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend#using-docker) will allow the use of 10000 locations:

`docker run -t -i -p 5000:5000 -v "${PWD}:/data" osrm/osrm-backend osrm-routed --algorithm mld --max-table-size 10000 /data/berlin-latest.osrm`

Answer (score 0):

```
dfm = osrmTable(src = df, dst = df)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).