# Is it possible to create a docker image within my own R package to be able to run an osrm-backend server?

Tags: r, docker, r-package, osrm

I am trying to use `osrm::osrmTable()` function to calculate a driving time distance matrix in my user-defined R package. Since the demo server from `osrm` package has a limit of 1000 queries I want to bypass it by creating a backend instance of the server locally using a docker container for that reason. I am new to docker, so I am not sure how can this be done in my R package.

The idea to create a backend instance comes from this other question answer, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74997208/how-to-speed-up-code-that-finds-shortest-driving-time-between-two-sets-of-points)

The final product should be a docker container with a backend instance of the `osrm` server in my R package.